# How to add subscript in a vertex in tikz-latex?

Tags: latex, tikz

The problem I am facing is that I can define the label for each vertex, but then when I move to position the vertices south, or east, that just creates a new vertex.

```
\begin{figure}
\tikzstyle{VertexStyle} = [shape = ellipse,minimum width= 6ex,draw]
\tikzstyle{EdgeStyle}   = [->,>=stealth']      
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5, auto=left,every node/.style={circle}]  
\SetGraphUnit{4} 
\Vertex[L=$x_{1}$]{x};
\Vertex[L=$h_{1}$]{h};
\EA(x){h}
\Edges(x)(h)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

Following is the output I get then:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For your code, line-by-line, the following is happening:

```
\Vertex[L=$x_{1}$]{x};
```

This creates a vertex (at the origin) with the name `x` and a `L`abel `$x_1$`.

```
\Vertex[L=$h_{1}$]{h};
```

This also creates a vertex (at the origin) with the name `h` with a `L`abel `$h_1$`.

```
\EA(x){h}
```

Here you add a vertex `h` to the `EA`st of `x`. The label name is `h` as well as the label.

```
\Edges(x)(h)
```

Now you *try* to add an edge between `x` and `h`.

---

Perhaps this is something that you might be interested in:

```
\Vertex[x = 1cm, L = $x_1$]{x};
```

Place a vertex called `x` with a `L`abel `$x_1$` (`1cm` east of the origin, just because).

```
\Vertex[x = 4cm, L = $h_1$]{h};
```

Place a vertex `h` with `L`abel `$h_1$` (`4cm` east of the origin, just so it doesn't sit on/close to `x`).

```
\Edges(x,h)
```

Draw an edge between nodes `x` and `h`.

```
\SetVertexMath
```

Node names and labels will include math content.

```
\EA(h){h_2}
```

Create a new vertex `h_2` to the `EA`st of `h`.

```
\Edges(h,h_2)
```

Draw another edge between `h` and `h_2`.

Here is a complete minimal example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tkz-berge}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \tikzstyle{VertexStyle} = [
    shape = ellipse,
    minimum width = 6ex,
    draw]
  \tikzstyle{EdgeStyle}   = [
    ->,
    > = stealth']      
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
    \SetGraphUnit{4} 
    \Vertex[x = 1cm, L = $x_1$]{x};
    \Vertex[x = 4cm, L = $h_1$]{h};
    \Edges(x,h)
    \SetVertexMath
    \EA(h){h_2}
    \Edges(h,h_2)
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```